# list of lists - assigning values inside of list of lists to variables, changing values inside of list of lists due to local variable functions

Tags: python, list, function

Title probably doesn't make sense, i just don't know how to put describe the help I need in a single sentence. So,
I have a list of lists

```
team_list[[teamname, gamesplayed, gameswon, gameslost,health [teamname2,gamesplayed,gameswon, gameslost,health][teamname3,gamesplayed,gameswon, gameslost,health]]
```

each list inside the team_list variable has the teams name, how many games they've played, won, lost and the teams health (0-100). there are more teams in the list, but for simplicity i'll leave it at 3.

I want to create a function which takes the list of teams and position of the two teams that are about to go against each other, position being the index of the team name stored in the list of characters. This is what i have created

```
def match(team_list, teamname1_pos, teamname2_pos)
```

I want the function to take input from the user who will type in the name of 2 teams they want to verse each other

```
team1 = input('Please select team:')
team2 = input('Please select team:')
```

The user will know the name of the teams from another function inside this program. If the name of the team isn't found in the list, the user will need to re enter team name. If the name of the team is found in the list, assign team variable to that list. **I have no idea on how i am supposed to write this in code**

I also want the function to take input from the user who will select how many rounds they want the match to go for

```
battle_rounds = int(input('How many rounds would you like to go for?')
```

and a battle round counter to store how many rounds have been played so the battle stops once it hits that number

```
num_of_battles = 0
```

and a damage variable that is generated randomly which will effect the 2 teams health (index 4) chosen by the users

```
damage = random.randint(1,50)
```

The match must stop once one of the players health is at 0, or once the amount of rounds chosen by the user is reached. The values inside the list of list much change, eg if team 1 takes 50 damage (starts at 100 damage), but team2 takes 100 damage, both teams games played must be increased by 1, team 1 wins increased by 1, team 2s loses increased by 1, team 1s health reduced to 50 and teams 2s health reduced to 0.

I have come up with an algorithm for how I think it should work, i am just very confused on how to implement this into code:

while (number of matches have not been completed and both opponents health are >0)
randomly generate a damage value sustained from match and update team's health value by calling method update_health(damage1).

randomly generate a damage value sustained from battle and update team2's health value by calling method update_health(damage2).

display team1 round results, display team2 round results

determine the winner of the match - the team with the most health left at the end of all the match rounds is the winner.
display the winner to the screen and also report if a team has died as a result of match.

update team1's battle statistics.
update team2's battle statistics.

Any help, no matter how big or small is welcomed
Thank you if you have read this far.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I would like to suggest using dictionary to solve the variable assigning problem.

```
team_dict= {"teamname": ["gamesplayed", "gameswon", "gameslost", "health"], "teamname2": ["gamesplayed", "gameswon", "gameslost", "health"],"teamname3": ["gamesplayed", "gameswon", "gameslost", "health"]}
```

since your data is more referential it would be more appropriate to use dictionaries. then loop over the keys to show the user the teams they can choose:

```
print(f"here are the teams you can choose from:")
for index,team in enumerate(team_dict,1):
    print(f"{index}. {team}")
team1 = team_dict[input('Please select team:')]
team2 = team_dict[input('Please select team:')]
```

I hope that helped.